# Python if statement not working (wrong result)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random

This one will be basic for you guys at stack overflow. I am trying to run the below code but no matter what I get for the placement variable points is always 0:

```
import random
number_disks =  random.randint( 1, 5 )  
user_input = ( "Congratulations you have " + str(number_disks) + "disks to 
play with." )
disk_count = 1
hit_count = 0
placement = 0
points = 0
while disk_count <= number_disks:
    print("Droppping disk " + str( disk_count ) + "..." )
    while hit_count != 5:
        hit_direction = random.randint( 0, 1 )
        if hit_direction == 0:
            print( "-Tick-" )
            placement = placement + 1
        elif hit_direction == 1:
            print( "-Tock-" )
            placement = placement - 1
        hit_count = hit_count + 1
    if placement == 5 or -5 or -1 or 1:
        points = 0
    elif placement == 4 or -4:
        points = 100
    elif placement == 3 or -3:
    points = 500
    elif placement == 2 or -2:
        points = 1000
    elif placement == 0:
        points = 10000
    print( str( placement ) )
    print( str( points ) )
    print( "The disk landed in $" + str( points ) + ", Congratulations!" )
    disk_count = disk_count + 1
    hit_count = 0
    placement = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for edit. Not sure why it went like that.

Comment: Tip: use `abs()` to take the absolute value. Compare only the positive value

Comment: i went to the proposed duplicate and that solved it for me. Thanks cricket_007

Comment: this question is asked (and closed) almost every day. There _must_ be something wrong with python (or python teachers :))